# Is it possible to make a link clickable while it's behind an image?

Tags: css, image, hyperlink, navigation, transparency

I have an image with transparency that spills over into a navigation menu a little bit (for design purposes). Is it possible to make the links clickable where there is overlap between the image and the links? Currently, the links are not clickable within the bounds of the image box, even in transparent areas. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set [`pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) on this image so that mouse interaction sort of goes through the image to elements behind it, like if image was not there:

```
img {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! In all my CSS Googling, I have never even heard of this attribute. Thanks for your quick reply! :)

Comment: EDIT: It should be noted that this also prevented any dragging or right-clicking of the image. It's probably basic knowledge that 'pointer-events: none;' does all of these things, but I'm including it in the answer for quick reference.

Comment: @JonNelsonMedia Correct, thank you! However in this case I don't think it will be a problem, because image is used for design purposes and not supposed to be interacted with.

Answer (score -1):

try setting the link css to the following (assuming the link has a class assigned to it):

```
.link{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
```